# How to create a (integer or numeric) variable based on a second one, but conditioned to many AND & OR conditions on third variables

Tags: r, variables, multiple-conditions

I'm just a little undergrad student and I apologize for my silly question, but I really cannot go further in replicating an article I've found on the Internet.
The code is available in Stata, but not in R.

Here the Stata Code, being each line a condition to me met by third variables, so the one I want to create just import the values of the second one.

```
gen child_care_basic = tuactdur24 if
(tutier1code==3 & tutier2code ==1 & tutier3code==1) |
```

[...]

What I tried in R was:

```
timeuse_2003$CHILD_CARE_BASIC <- NA
timeuse_2003$CHILD_CARE_BASIC[(timeuse_2003$TUTIER1CODE==3 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER2CODE==1 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER3CODE==1) |
                          (timeuse_2003$TUTIER1CODE==3 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER2CODE==1 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER3CODE==1) |
                          (timeuse_2003$TUTIER1CODE==3 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER2CODE==1 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER3CODE==8) |
                          (timeuse_2003$TUTIER1CODE==3 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER2CODE==1 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER3CODE==9) |
                          (timeuse_2003$TUTIER1CODE==3 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER2CODE==1 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER3CODE==10) |
                          (timeuse_2003$TUTIER1CODE==3 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER2CODE==1 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER3CODE==11) |
                          (timeuse_2003$TUTIER1CODE==3 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER2CODE==1 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER3CODE==12) |
                          (timeuse_2003$TUTIER1CODE==3 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER2CODE==1 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER3CODE==99) |
                          (timeuse_2003$TUTIER1CODE==3 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER2CODE==3) |
                          (timeuse_2003$TUTIER1CODE==4 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER2CODE==1 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER3CODE==1) |
                          (timeuse_2003$TUTIER1CODE==4 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER2CODE==1 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER3CODE==8) |
                          (timeuse_2003$TUTIER1CODE==4 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER2CODE==1 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER3CODE==9) |
                          (timeuse_2003$TUTIER1CODE==4 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER2CODE==1 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER3CODE==10) |
                          (timeuse_2003$TUTIER1CODE==4 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER2CODE==1 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER3CODE==10) |
                          (timeuse_2003$TUTIER1CODE==4 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER2CODE==1 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER3CODE==10) |
                          (timeuse_2003$TUTIER1CODE==4 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER2CODE==1 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER3CODE==10) |
                          (timeuse_2003$TUTIER1CODE==4 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER2CODE==3 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER3CODE==10) |
                          (timeuse_2003$TUTIER1CODE==17 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER2CODE==3 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER3CODE==10) |
                          (timeuse_2003$TUTIER1CODE==17 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER2CODE==4 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER3CODE==10) |
                          (timeuse_2003$TUTIER1CODE==17 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER2CODE==4 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER3CODE==1)
                          ]<- timeuse_2003$TUACTDUR24
```

The problem is, I only got NAs in the entire column.

Again, I apologize for such a basic question, but I just tried a lot of different things and nothing worked, so I decided to ask you guys outta of my beginner's box.

Thank you in advance.

Fabricio

Comment: I am curious why you replaced the == operator from Stata with != in R. Wouldn't you expect the opposite to happen? Perhaps you can give us a small data sample and show us the expected behavior. Also show your code and either the error message you are getting or the wrong result.

Comment: Hi BigFinger, thank you. It was actually a workaround I was trying to implement. Frist, I created the variable by just duplicating the second one. Then I wanted to suppress some values with NAs, that just don't match those conditions on third variables. I reedited the question to make it tidy. I'm getting an error message: the command doesn't run at all:

Error: unexpected ']' in: 
(timeuse_2003$TUTIER1CODE!=4 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER2CODE!=1 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER3CODE!=10) |
(timeuse_2003$TUTIER1CODE!=4 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER2CODE!=3 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER3CODE!=10))]"

Comment: ps. I've seen a lot of posts on how to create variables on conditions, but they return logical values. I want my variable to be created with values of the second one and not with TRUEs or FALSEs. Thank you.

Comment: Again, it would help to post the actual code you ran and the error message you got. The error you describe in the comment does not match the code you posted in the question. For example, the error mentions timeuse_2003$TUTIER1CODE!=4. You do not have a value of 4 in the R code in the question. The error message indicates a parenthesis mismatch, but without seeing your actual code it is impossible to tell where it happened.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance, BigFinger. Now I have just copied the entire code and the error message. I would like to know from you if the code makes sense at all, taking my purpose into account: create a new variable from a second one, given (many AND/OR) conditions on third variables. Could you give me an example, maybe? So I could try to derive an alternative. My purpose is to get fluency in R with this replication.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, you have mismatched parentheses. There is a closing parenthesis missing. I suspect is in the line that ends with 99, but please double-check your logic. Otherwise the syntax looks correct. If you are still getting errors, please send the output of str(timeuse_2003).

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still geting an error, even after correcting the missing parentheses. Here the error:

Error in timeuse_2003$TUTIER1CODE == 3 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER2CODE == 1 &  : 
  could not find function "&<-"

I don't know if this information is valuable, but once I have the Stata code online and the code files are really long, I just manipulated it in Excel and pasted it on R. 

The str(timeuse_2003)-output was too long to post. The dataset has 412611 obs. and 65 variables. Can I provide you something else?

Comment: After deleting all "group-conditions" and let only the first, this is what happens:

timeuse_2003$CHILD_CARE_BASIC <- timeuse_2003$TUACTDUR24[(timeuse_2003$TUTIER1CODE0==3 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER2CODE==1 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER3CODE==1)]


Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, CHILD_CARE_BASIC, value = integer(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 412611

Comment: I just noticed another error, there should be a == here: timeuse_2003$TUTIER3CODE=12

Comment: Oh, one other big thing: You should not subselect and then assign to another column. The number of rows will be mismatched. Can you please post the output of the following 2 commands: 1. typeof(timeuse_2003), 2. head(timeuse_2003)

Comment: I corrected all this typos but nothing works... I already changed the position of the conditions (right, left), in brackets, parenthesis, both... even reducing all conditions to only one doesn't seem to help.

Comment: > typeof(timeuse_2003)
[1] "list"


To the second command, is unfortunately pretty long for posting

Comment: Thank your for your time, BigFinger

Comment: That is surprising. Please also send: 1. class(timeuse_2003), 2. attributes(timeuse_2003), 3. str(timeuse_2003[1:10,1:5]), 4. timeuse_2003[1:10,1:5]

Comment: TY.
1. > class(timeuse_2003)
[1] "data.frame"
2. > attributes(timeuse_2003) [too long to post]
$names
 [1] "TUCASEID"         "TULINENO"         "GESTFIPS"         "GEREG"            "PEEDUCA"   
 
$row.names
   [1]    1    2    3 ...

3. > str(timeuse_2003[1:10,1:5])
'data.frame': 10 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ TUCASEID:Class 'labelled' num  2e+13 2e+13 2e+13 2e+13 2e+13 ...
   .. .. LABEL: ATUS Case ID (14-digit identifier) 
 $ TULINENO:Class 'labelled' int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
   .. .. LABEL: ATUS person line number 
 $ GESTFIPS:Class 'labelled' int  6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6

...

Comment: 4. > timeuse_2003[1:10,1:5] 
      TUCASEID TULINENO GESTFIPS GEREG PEEDUCA
1  2.00301e+13        1        6     4      44
2  2.00301e+13        1        6     4      44
3  2.00301e+13        1        6     4      44
4  2.00301e+13        1        6     4      44
5  2.00301e+13        1        6     4      44
6  2.00301e+13        1        6     4      44
7  2.00301e+13        1        6     4      44
8  2.00301e+13        1        6     4      44
9  2.00301e+13        1        6     4      44
10 2.00301e+13        1        6     4      40

Comment: Could you please give me an example, how would you do that, for ex. you have a variable X that you want to create, based on variable Y. The values would be copied from y to x only if condition z, w, r were met.

Comment: Hey BigFinger, please take a look at the updated question. I changed the code and got no error message this time. The only problem is, I only have NAs in the column, and I was supposed to get some values, abide of the NAs, as well.
Thank you

Comment: ok, I think we are getting close. Could you please add the output of the following to the question, so that it is formatted nicely? timeuse_2003[1:20, c("TUACTDUR24", "TUTIER1CODE", "TUTIER2CODE", "TUTIER3CODE")]

Comment: You got it! When I tried to look at TUTIER3CODE I've noticed that the variable wasn't defined (NULL). I just repeated TUTIER2CODE (the code is very, very long. I wish I could break it in several scripts to be run from a master script). Thanks a lot!
The only thing remaining is the error (?) message:


Warning message:
In timeuse_2003$CHILD_CARE_BASIC[(timeuse_2003$TUTIER1CODE == 3 &  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Is that a issue at all? The values seems pretty consistent with those of Stata.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem I was talking about earlier. You are selecting a subset of values and are attempting to assign them to the full number of rows, thus the conflict in number of items. I am going to post an answer below, which whows you the pattern you should use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the pattern below to create a new column with a subset of values based on your business logic.

```
timeuse_2003 = data.frame(
    TUACTDUR24 = c(10.1, 20.2, 30.3, 40.4, 50.5),
    TUTIER1CODE = c(3, 4, 3, 4, 3),
    TUTIER2CODE = c(1, 1, 1, 3, 3))

timeuse_2003

  TUACTDUR24 TUTIER1CODE TUTIER2CODE
1       10.1           3           1
2       20.2           4           1
3       30.3           3           1
4       40.4           4           3
5       50.5           3           3

selection = timeuse_2003$TUTIER1CODE==3 & timeuse_2003$TUTIER2CODE==1
timeuse_2003$CHILD_CARE_BASIC = NA
timeuse_2003$CHILD_CARE_BASIC[selection] = timeuse_2003$TUACTDUR24[selection]

timeuse_2003

  TUACTDUR24 TUTIER1CODE TUTIER2CODE CHILD_CARE_BASIC
1       10.1           3           1             10.1
2       20.2           4           1               NA
3       30.3           3           1             30.3
4       40.4           4           3               NA
5       50.5           3           3               NA
```

Comment: That worked just perfectly fine. Thank you very much for your patience and effort. 
Once we got this far, I would like to ask you what you meant with "You should not subselect and then assign to another column. The number of rows will be mismatched." and why your solution has the conditions on both sides of the assignment (to CHILD_CARE_BASIC and TUACTDUR24)?

Comment: I am glad we were able to figure it out. To your question: In the example above, timeuse_2003$TUACTDUR24[selection] is a vector with 2 elements. If you assign timeuse_2003$CHILD_CARE_BASIC = timeuse_2003$TUACTDUR24[selection], you are assigning a vector of 2 elements to a vector with 5 elements. Although R will happily allow it, it will not give you the expected result. If you do the same selection on both sides of the assignment, like timeuse_2003$CHILD_CARE_BASIC[selection] = timeuse_2003$TUACTDUR24[selection], then the values will be assigned to the correct index positions.

Comment: I see. Thank your for sharing your knowledge!